# What size metric wire is required for 240 VAC 30 Amps located in house with run of 90M or <100 feet to a garage

Tags: wiring

What size metric wire is required from a 240 VAC 30 Amps breaker located in house with run of 90M or <100 feet to a garage for washer, drier, fridge and lighting on 3 X 10 amp and 1 X 5 amp breakers located in the garage. And, please give me the URL for a good conversion site, Thanks.

Comment: What does "90M or <100 feet" mean?  90 meters is ~300 feet?  And for the URL, what do you want to convert?

Comment: What size wire is *required* may vary with your location in the world. Engineering and legal requirements sometimes are the same, but often are not.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: It's really a question of what your local government requires.  Also, 90m is ~<100 yards (think strides) which is more like 300 feet.  Don't be surprised if you need 4 or 2 AWG to make that make sense. And at that size you should really be in aluminum so 0 or 00 AWG might even be called for.

Comment: How much does the drier take? Given the 10A breaker, I'm assuming 10A? You could probably get away with a 20A feed.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, a 30 ampere circuit would use 10 AWG conductors.  10 AWG is 5.261 mm². However, if you're going 90 meters (295 feet), you might have to compensate for voltage drop. You might go up to 8 AWG (8.367 mm²), or possibly even 6 AWG (13.3 mm²).

These figures are based on codes in the US, so you'll have to check local codes before proceeding.

[EngineeringToolbox.com](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com) has a good [conversation chart](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/awg-wire-gauge-d_731.html) to go from AWG to mm².

Answer (score 0):

Based on [BS7671](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS_7671), for a 5% voltage drop, with cable in conduit, you need 16mm² according to the calculator at http://www.doncastercables.com/technical-help/ but it depends on the cable type as well.

The calculator at http://myelectrical.com/tools/cable-sizing-calculator suggest a larger 25mm² cable for amoured cable buried directly in the ground. You could use a smaller cable if you are willing to accept a larger voltage drop or use a different cable type or installation method.

You probably need to pay an expert to work this out.

Comment: I would probably go for <5% drop - there's also going to be drop from the boundary to the main board, and then in the final subcircuits.